# Applescript Error -10810

Tags: macos, applescript

I have an Applescript that runs fine on my Macbook Retina but fails on a Mac Mini.

Both are running MacOS 10.9.2.

After peeling the onion a bit I'm able to reproduce the problem with a one-line Applescript:

```
tell application "MidiPipe" to activate
```

On the Mini that throws the error:

```
An error of type -10810 has occurred.
```

On the Macbook the MidiPipe application opens.

MidiPipe works normally on the Mini when started from the Finder or from Launchpad.

Google provides no insight into this error.

Comment: Is the Mini running the same version of MidiPipe?

Comment: Have you tried removing and reinstalling MidiPipe on the mini?  Perhaps a botched install is to blame?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I found this: http://www.thexlab.com/faqs/error-10810.html and this: http://osxdaily.com/2010/02/09/mac-error-10810/ and this: http://forums.adobe.com/thread/1389805 . At least one of these suggests a RAM problem.

But just to make sure you've tried every weird variation, have you tried the following:

1) using a full path:

```
tell application "Full:Path:To:MidiPipe.app" --(probably "YourHDName:Applications:MidiPipe.app"?
```

2) using an actual tell block:

```
tell application "MidiPipe"--or full path
 activate
end tell
```

3) using the Finder:

```
tell application "Finder" to open "Full:Path:To:MidiPipe.app"
```

4) using shell:
do shell script "open /Applications/MidiPipe.app"

?

Comment: Trying to figure out how to put line breaks into these comments while holding appplescript anomolies in my head risks explosion, so I'm going to do this a several consecutive comments:

Comment: Solution #1 works!    This despite the fact that other applications can be opened with the short form.  Just not MidiPipe.  e.g:  
`tell application "Wirecast" to activate`

Comment: Solution #2 **does not work** as shown above, but **does** work if the full path is supplied.   An actual tell block was the form in the original script before I started peeling things down to essentials.   Note that if I enter the name as `MidiPipe.app` without using the full path, the copiler drops the extension.

Comment: Solution #3 does work.  Likely because it uses the full path to MidiPipe.app.

Comment: And, of course, solution #4 works.  I was avoiding solving Applescript problems by dropping into the shell in a delusional attempt to master Applescript itself, including understanding when and how to use the myriad different ways to declare paths and locations.  Being a bear of very little brain, I _didn't_ understand that is an entirely futile undertaking as proven by the fact that some programs in the Applications directory can be started by name and some cannot (see comment re Solution #1).  Many thanks for the help! This **has** been an education!

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, @RichardMilewski! Some people end up forgiving AppleScript its quirks, some curse the language forever because of them. I'm somewhere in between, but more on the former side.

Answer (score 3):

After looking at the links in [CRGreen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23399310/2348587), it looks like this is likely being caused by the process table being full on the mini. This, in turn, prevents any new applications from opening. According to [The X Lab](http://www.thexlab.com/faqs/error-10810.html):

> Error -10810 is a Launch Services result code indicating an unknown error. One cause of this error is that the Mac® OS X process table is full. When the process table is full, new (not currently running) applications cannot be opened until another running application ends. Programming errors in third-party applications can fill-up the process table, leading to the -10810 error when opening an application.

I would start by restarting the mini to see if that clears the process table, allowing you to to start MidiPipe.

If that doesn't work, you should look at your Activity Monitor to see if there is a specific program filling up your process table.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but alas, it's pretty clearly not a full process table, unless there's something about how that limit is enforced that I don't understand.

On the freshly rebooted mini there are about 160 process running about 750 threads.  After a minute or two that calms down to 128 processes running 536 threads.  Executing the script then still causes the error.   

See my reply to CRGreen's answer for my argument as to why this is just Applescript being dysfunctional and arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

Could be nothing more than another mysterious grieving crap from Apple.

Today I have faced this myself, first time after using four different Mac Minis as build servers for Continuous Integration of Mobile apps for about two years or so.

My Jenkins runs the osascript from the bash script to build the app.

A few days ago the office experienced the power outage and all Macs went down. After powering them back on I have got this error at osascript execution on one of my Macs.

I have tried just to re-build - with the same result.

First thing I stumbled upon was https://jacobsalmela.com/2014/08/04/infamous-execution-error-error-type-10810-occurred-10810/ , but none of them applied to me.

Then I googled more general 10810 issue occurrences and went through couple of questions here on SO.

Still no luck.

Next I reached to the server via SSH using PuTTY and tried telling Terminal to do the very basic script like

```
 osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal"
 activate
 tell window 1
 do script "counter=0; while true; do if [ \"$counter\" -gt \"10\" ]; then
     break; else counter=$((counter + 1)); sleep 1; fi; done; exit;"
 end tell
 end tell'
```

This worked fine.

Then I tried to run the whole bash script that Jenkins used to execute. Everything went just perfect and the app was uploaded to HockeyApp as the result.

I came with the thought that the issue is that Jenkins runs it remotely on that Mac and finally I have tried just to re-build again and it magically worked fine this time.

No idea what it was, but since then I have performed three or more builds already and all of them were successful.

Note I haven't changed anything, and my script:

1) *never* used a full path;

2) *always* used an actual tell block;

3,4) nothing like that from the accepted answer was ever used.

So... Go away mysterious grieving crap! Go away! :)