# AppleScript: execution error -10810 when launching certain applications from shebang'ed scripts

Tags: applescript

I'm running OS X 10.10.2. I'm facing a weird issue where AppleScript won't launch applications from shebang'ed scripts while working fine everywhere else (Script Editor, piping to `osascript`, etc.). Specifically, consider the following example script named `launch-app`:

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript
launch application "TextEdit"
```

When TextEdit is not running and I do

```
./launch-app
```

I get

```
./launch-app:0:29: execution error: An error of type -10810 has occurred. (-10810)
```

When I do

```
<launch-app osascript
```

Well, it works just fine; which means the following Bash script will also work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
osascript <<EOF
launch application "TextEdit"
EOF
```

Really weird. (By the way, a `tell ... activate ... end tell` block results in the same error. I'm using `launch` here just to keep to example minimal.)

I have some old scripts that involve activating an application (well, practically all my old scripts involve `tell ... activate ... end tell`) that definitely worked in the past. I can't tell when things began to fall apart because when I run those scripts, most often the applications to `activate` are already launched. I have the impression that the issue dates back at least to 10.10.1.

I have looked at several related posts here on SO, e.g., [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23398435/applescript-error-10810), but they don't help. I also tried to understand error -10810 by reading articles like [this one](http://www.thexlab.com/faqs/error-10810.html), but my problem definitely doesn't look like a filled process table (otherwise why does directly calling `osascript` works while running `osascript` from a shebang doesn't?).

Comment: Have you tried on a different machine (running the same OS version)? The script looks OK (it runs fine on my OSX 10.10.2 machine).

Comment: I also get this error when attempting to run the script file from the terminal. I'm on 10.10.1.

Comment: @mklement0 Unfortunately I only have one machine running 10.10. I can set up a virtual environment but that seems an overkill. I'll test on 10.8 though when I have time.

Comment: @CRGreen Thanks for the feedback! Then maybe it's an OS X problem.

Comment: @zmwangx: We already know that the problem doesn't surface on _all_ OSX 10.10.2 machines - your script runs fine on mine. Have you checked Console.app for entries?

Comment: @mklement0 Good point. The console log says "1/30/15 2:05:42.421 PM TextEdit[21620]: No Info.plist file in application bundle or no NSPrincipalClass in the Info.plist file, exiting". Not sure how that's possible, especially given that the script works fine for all other ways of calling.

Comment: @zmwangx: Curious indeed. Btw, I missed the aspect of the error only surfacing when the app is _not_ running - I indeed now see the same symptom on my machine (ditto for `run application` and `activate application`, and even `do shell script "open -g -a TextEdit"`). Probably worth reporting the bug to Apple.

Comment: @mklement0 Hmm, I didn't realize even `do shell script` won't work. I have filed a bug report with Apple. By the way, I just tested the same thing on 10.8.5 and as expected it works just define. I don't have a 10.9 environment at hand.

Comment: @zmwangx: Just tried it - it works just fine on 10.9 as well.

Comment: Btw, the error also surfaces when you pass a script _filename_ to `osascript`.

Comment: @mklement0 stdin works, file doesn't...

Comment: @zmwangx: That's a good summary, thanks.

Comment: Good news: The issue has finally been resolved in 10.10.*3*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: The bug has been **fixed** in **OSX 10.10.3**.

---

Just to provide a state-of-the-union post:

The behavior observed is a ***bug* in OSX 10.10 still unresolved as of OSX 10.10.2** (as of 10 Mar 2015):

**Anyone interested in getting this fixed should file their own bug at http://bugreport.apple.com.**

It applies to ***executable* scripts** that are ***directly or indirectly* passed to `osascript`** - whether:

- explicitly (`osascript launch-app`)
- or implicitly, via the shebang line, by direct invocation (`./launch-app`)

The specific form of the shebang line is irrelevant (whether `#!/usr/bin/osascript` or `#!/usr/bin/env osascript` or `#!/usr/bin/env osascript -l JavaScript` or ...), **what matters is whether the file has the executable bit (permission) set** (e.g., via `chmod +x`).

**Workarounds**:

- As suggested by the OP, **feed the file to `osascript` via *stdin***: `osascript < launch-app`

  - This has **side effects**; for instance, `name of me` will report `msng` instead of the name of the script.
- **Remove the executable bit from the script and invoke it explicitly with `osascript`**:

  - `chmod -x launch-app  # a one-time operation`
  - `osascript launch-app # with the executable bit unset, this should work`

Comment: I already filed one a while ago. I didn't file it in OpenRadar though.

Comment: @zmwangx: I have no experience with OpenRadar - do you think it's worth doing? (P.S.: I know you did; so have I. The intent was to encourage _others_ to file a bug report, too.)

Comment: It's just a good way to share bugs you've filed so that others can search and find out that they are not alone – bugs you file with Apple are confidential AFAIK.

Comment: @zmwangx: Got it. Voilà: http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=5864388946821120  (the report essentially just points back here).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the man page for osascript, when you send lines of applescript code you should put the "-e" option infront of each separate line.

So here's what I tested. I made a bash script with the -e option...

```
#!/bin/bash
osascript -e 'launch application "TextEdit"'
```

And one without.

```
#!/bin/bash
osascript 'launch application "TextEdit"'
```

The one without the -e option does not run. As such I think this could be a cause of your problem... there's no -e option in your code.

Note that I tested your code too and got the same error as you. There's a command line utility "/usr/bin/macerror" and I entered your error code into that. Here's the result.

```
Unknown error (-10810) at /usr/bin/macerror5.18 line 40, <DATA> line 1.
```

Good luck.

Comment: I'm not in front of my Mac right now, but no, that's not the problem. My shebang is correct, and my scripts run fine except when the application to activate is not already running.

Comment: Note that your problematic script is not equivalent to mine at all.

Comment: Your shebang is correct and yet it doesn't run? My script is problematic and yet it runs? Please explain your comments rather than make definite statements. I at least tried to give you a considered answer. The least you can do is afford me the same courtesy. Your comment about "not already running" makes no sense as the launch command should work regardless of the state of the application.

Comment: I'll get back to you when I'm in front my Mac (not on my phone), but I hope you can understand my question before answering. Also from your answer it seems that you don't have much expertise with osascript.

Comment: Another insult. My time with you is over.

Comment: No problem. Honestly I'm already polite enough about your clueless answer. Do you even understand my two example scripts? Do you understand what the shebang #!/use/bin/osascript means? Either you don't or you won't read the question. Don't be so butthurt, this is what you get when the answer shows no clue at all. Why don't we delete the answer and the unhappy comments?

Comment: @Zero Thanks for testing. You might have noticed that my problematic script uses a `#!/usr/bin/osascript` shebang, rather than calling `osascript` followed by the script content in a bash script. You might also have noticed that I provided a *working* bash script that passes the AppleScript from stdin. So this answer is simply irrelevant — addressing a mistake that I has never made and has nothing to do with my problem at hand.

Comment: btw there have been discussions about similar problems, with some confusion about it being a "process table" error, which I don't think it is (technically). It seems to be a bug in LSOpenURLsWithRole().

Comment: While it's good to know about the `macerror` utility in general, its output in this case simply indicates that lookup of the error _failed_, i.e., that `macerror` cannot retrieve information about this error (no idea, why). The actual error information - taken from `LSInfo.h` - is: `kLSUnknownErr                 = -10810, /* Unexpected internal error*/`, for which the OP has already provided a link to background information in his question (http://www.thexlab.com/faqs/error-10810.html).

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for using osascript to launch applications. There is a built in command line utility named open, that will open your app from the terminal commandline, or a shebanged script. For doucumentation, enter "man open" in a terminal window. It is a really nifty utility, with a lot of options. :)

The open utility, will lauch applications that are not running, but I also wonder out of curiosity: have you tried "tell application appname to run", or just "tell application appname to activate"?

The osascript below, works for me, on 10.9

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript
tell application "TextEdit" to launch
```

I guess you'll have to commmand the app to do something, and not just try to "launch" it. Maybe "tell me to launch application appname also works".

**Edit**

I prefer to use open -b "com.apple.textedit", because then I also get the front window of textEdit, brought to front.

By the way, with the open -e command, you can open a textfile directly into TextEdit from the commandline. open is not totally as good as the plumb utility of plan-9, but it is really nifty.

Comment: Thanks for telling me about `open`, but no thanks, I know it perfectly well, for years. The example scripts here are just minimal working examples used in bug reports, not meant for the real world. So please stick to the question. About the real world: `tell application ... activate ... end tell`, which also launches an application if it is not already running and which appears in almost every AppleScript, also breaks, as I pointed out in the question.

Comment: "I also wonder out of curiosity: have you tried "tell application appname to run", or just "tell application appname to activate"?" This is answered in the question itself, it you read carefully.

Comment: About the only relevant part of the answer, i.e., "works for me on 10.9", this is already confirmed in the comments. Works on 10.9 and below, broken on 10.10.